# Why are my converters called in a hidden window?

Tags: wpf, imultivalueconverter

I have a `Grid` with some child windows. Some of these children have a `MultiBinding` with a complicated converter. Now, if I hide the grid (`Collapsed` or `Hidden`) the converters are still being called. Why?!

When I hide an UI element I expect the renderer to completely skip its visual tree. More specifically, I want my converters not to be called when they are operating in a "hidden" context! Ideas?

Comment: Imagine you have Visibility of one of your controls bound to a property in your VM.  How is it going to know when to show the control again if bindings never got updated when a control isn't visible?  I don't think there is a way around aside from removing the control from the visual tree completely. Just because a property is set doesn't mean it doesn't exist in the visual tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when an element's `Visibility` property is `Collapsed` or `Hidden` it remains a part of the logical tree and therefore it is perfectly normal that the converters continue to work while the element is not visible.

One simple solution to disable value conversion while the element is Collapsed or Hidden is to use the [ConverterParameter Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converterparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), bind it to element's Visibility property and in the converter check if this property is set to Collapsed or Hidden and skip the conversion if it is...

There might be a more elegant solution but this should do the trick if no one thinks of a better approach short of removing the element from the logical tree altogether...

Comment: I'm not sure about this, that's why I didn't include it in the answer but I think if you also disable the control when you change it's visibility to Collapsed or Hidden it will also disable the value conversion... could you try that and let me know how that worked?

Comment: Setting `IsEnabled="False"` on the top-parent `UIElement` does not help. My converters are still being called.